# Vim solarized colorscheme does not work correctly

Tags: linux, vim, terminal, archlinux, color-scheme

I am new user to Vim and I have installed Solarized colorscheme. Unfortunately, the colorscheme does not look how it should. I tried running test for testing terminal color palette and it works correctly:
[terminal color palette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXJJh.png)

While I run the vim and test the color palette it is definitely wrong:
[vim color palette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6nxM.png)

Here is my .vimrc configuration file:

```
call plug#begin()
        Plug 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
call plug#end()
leg g: solarized_termcolors=256
syntax enable
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
```

I also tried to hardcode `t_Co=256` in my .vimrc file, but it did not help.
`echo #TERM` says that my terminal is `xterm-256color`. I am using Manjaro KDE. Solarized on gVim works properly.

Comment: Could you please run me through the steps you took to install vim solarized?

Comment: I installed vim-plug using instructions mentioned on project's github website. Then I placed `Plug 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'` in between the lines meant for installation of vim plugins (as shown above in shared .vimrc file). I opened Vim and run `PlugInstall`, which installed the plugin. Then I opened the .vimrc again and added 4 last lines related to colorscheme configuration.

Comment: 1. Are you using true color in terminal? 2. what version of vim?

Comment: 1. As far as I know - yes. I had run couple of tests on this page: https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728 and results seem to be okay. 2. The version of vim is: `8.1`

Comment: I don't understand your problem. what is not correct?

Comment: The vim does not seem to display colors correctly (especially in solarized colorscheme). The colors work correctly on gvim, but not vim.